# Apache Nifi: append splitted processing results to the original FlowFile

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a Nifi flow with the `SplitJson` processor. Splitted parts are processing by some other processors and then the `Notify` processor notifies the `Wait` processor, and everything is good there. But I can't figure out how to transfer the changes of processing to the original `FlowFile` that waits at the `Wait` processor. I want to combine all the results at one place (probably at the original `Flowfile`) to do something with the final combined result, how can I do that?

Comment: I don't get it. When the `SplitJson` gets executed, it will actually produce flowfiles from two relations: split and original. You don't have to 'transfer' the split flowfiles to original. You can, however, merge if you want to combine them together.

Comment: The problem is that I need to know the information about processing my 'splitted' flowfiles at the `Wait` processor, but I have only the original flowfile there. Split flowfiles goes to processing and then to the `Notify` processor, and ends there.

Comment: Can you please export your current flow and share it? It would be easy for me to understand the flow and offer the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Edited original post with flow.xml. Can't use file sharing services due to security restrictions of my company :(

Comment: That's not a proper template xml, I think. I'm unable to upload. Select the entire flow by holding `shift` and dragging the mouse to cover all the processors and ports. Once selected, export them as a template. Then from the templates page, download it. Share it here or paste it in some online bin boards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, thanks to [SivaprasannaSethuraman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2973446/sivaprasanna-sethuraman)

I just have to merge my split flowfiles before calling `Notify` processor. And then at the `Wait` processor I have to wait only one event instead of waiting `${fragment.count}` events. So I have my expected merged result in that single event at the `Wait` processor.